# How to retrive full Wikidata info of an entity

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

I'm using different kind of queries to retrive wikidata info of an entity like, for Berlin:

- https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q64.json
- https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q64&format=json

but all of these did not include the full information.
As an example, i'm not able to find the official language or population data.

How can I get all data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[wikidata]+flavor

Comment: Thank for suggesting that resources, but both of them do not contain full information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the shown URLs / APIs do should you the full data for the entity that you are looking at, [Q64 being Berlin](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q64).

In Wikidata the official language is represented by the [Property P37](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P37) and the population by [Property P1082](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1082).

You will find references to these properties in the JSON output.
For example for the language:

```
{
  "mainsnak": {
    "snaktype": "value",
    "property": "P37",
    "hash": "b8dce904caadeef339763625b903974aa4c83c6a",
    "datavalue": {
      "value": {
        "entity-type": "item",
        "numeric-id": 188,
        "id": "Q188"
      },
      "type": "wikibase-entityid"
    },
    "datatype": "wikibase-item"
  },
  "type": "statement",
  "id": "Q64$9AEBFCE4-EC53-4A97-B20B-4579FBD32CE7",
  "rank": "normal"
}
```

This refers to [Q188 which is German](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q188).